# How to get the sum of two variables using two classes

Tags: java, class

How do I connect these two classes, so that class RationalNumber can get the calculation from class CameronH51?

Code From Rational Number:

```java
public class CameronH51 { 

      private int numerator1, denominator1;
   
      public void add()

    {
   
    System.out.print(numerator1 + denominator1);
    
    }
   

    }
```

Code From CameronH51:

```java
public class RationalNumber 
    {

    int numerator1 = 3 , denominator1 = 6;

    public static void main(String[] args)
   
    {
   
    CameronH51 object = new add();
   
    object.add();
  
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- create an instance of RationalNumber to access the fields to add
- create an instane of CameronH51 to call the add method
- print the result.

```
public class RationalNumber {
    
    int numerator1 = 3, denominator1 = 6;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RationalNumber rn = new RationalNumber();
        CameronH51 cameronInstance = new CameronH51();
        
        int result = cameronInstance.add(rn.numerator1,rn.denominator1);
        System.out.println("result = " + result);
    }
    
}


class CameronH51 {
    // add two numbers and return result
    public int add(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use static methods like the samples below:

```
public class A {

    public static double add(double number1, double number2){
        return number1+number2;
    }
}
```

and then use it in the other class:

```
public class B {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double result = A.add(5, 8);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the two numbers INTO your CameronH51 class.  The most common way to do this would be to add a CONSTRUCTOR that receives the two values:

```
public class CameronH51 { 

  private int numerator1, denominator1;
   
  public CameronH51(int num, int den) {
    numerator1 = num;
    denominator1 = den;
  }

  public void add() {  
    System.out.println(numerator1 + denominator1);
  }

}
```

Now, over in RationalNumber, you can create its own `Add()` method.  In that method you'd create an instance of CameronH51 (passing in the values from RationalNumber via the Constructor), and call the `Add()` method:

```
public class RationalNumber {

  private int numerator1 = 3;
  private int denominator1 = 6;

  public void add() {
    CameronH51 c = new CameronH51(numerator1, denominator1);
    c.add();
  }

}
```

Here's a class with `main()` tying everything together:

```
class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    RationalNumber rn = new RationalNumber();
    rn.add();
  }

}
```

Here's a link to a [Repl.it](https://repl.it/join/ijhpqxsx-idlemind) to play with.

With all that said, the design of the two classes seems a little off.  You may be approaching the problem wrong, but we don't know that without a better description...